# How to draw a ellipse with C?

Tags: c

I want to draw an ellipse but It isn't like a ellipse which I drew.
You can see my ellipse.

Which things should I change?
Briefly, how can ı draw a good ellipse?

In the code there is not an error.

That is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void Circle(int radius);



int main(void){
    int radius;
    Circle(5);
}


void Circle(int radius)
{
    int star,space;
    int i;
    int j;
    star=1;
    space=radius-1;

    for(i=1;i<=radius;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=space;j++){
              printf(" ");
         }
        for(j=1;j<=star;j++){
              printf("*");
         }
        space--;
        star+=2;
        printf("\n");
    }
    star-=4;


    for(i=1;i<radius;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=i;j++){
              printf(" ");
        }
        for(j=1;j<=star;j++){
              printf("*");
        }
        star-=2;
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: r^2 = (x - x_bias)^2+(y - y_bias)^2 ==> y = y_bias ± √(r^2-(x - x_bias)^2)

Comment: This has already been closed as a duplicate (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42612311/how-can-i-shift-right-my-equilateral-quadrangle-on-terminal-with-ci-am-beginne) twice making this a triplicate.  Can we get rid of this post (and the dups) please?

Answer (score 0):

Your circle function should look like this: The meat and potatoes of your function is `sqrt((j-(k)/2)*(j-(k)/2) + (i-(k)/2)*(i-(k)/2))<=radius`. The formula should look familiar if you've taken advanced math. k is surface and can be adjusted.

it essentially charts out your 50x50 surface area (or whatever k is). x,y are the different points along the plane.

(x-center)^2+(y-center)^2<=radius

```
void Circle(int radius) {
    int i,j;
    int k = 50;
    for (i=0; i<k; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<k; j++) {
            if(sqrt((j-(k)/2)*(j-(k)/2) + (i-(k)/2)*(i-(k)/2))<=radius)
                printf("*"); //meets criteria print *
            else
                printf(" "); //blank space
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

With a radius of 20:

```
                     *                        
               *************                  
             *****************                
           *********************              
         *************************            
        ***************************           
       *****************************          
      *******************************         
     *********************************        
     *********************************        
    ***********************************       
    ***********************************       
   *************************************      
   *************************************      
  ***************************************     
  ***************************************     
  ***************************************     
  ***************************************     
  ***************************************     
  ***************************************     
 *****************************************    
  ***************************************     
  ***************************************     
  ***************************************     
  ***************************************     
  ***************************************     
  ***************************************     
   *************************************      
   *************************************      
    ***********************************       
    ***********************************       
     *********************************        
     *********************************        
      *******************************         
       *****************************          
        ***************************           
         *************************            
           *********************              
             *****************                
               *************                  
                     *
```

if you don't want to use math.h you can define a custom sqrt:

```
double sqrt(float number)
{
    double precision = 0.001;
    double s = number;

    while ((s - number / s) > precision) {
        s = (s + number / s) / 2;
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: @myname That seems like a pretty arbitrary restriction. If that's a restriction that is part of your homework or whatever it is you need this for, then you should mention that and any others in the question.

Comment: @ApolloSoftware Can you solve the problem without sqrt .? I dont want to use math library.

Comment: @myname you can define a sqrt like function if you don't want to use math library?

Comment: @ApolloSoftware I can't.sqrt is very spesific function.

Comment: @myname i've added the sqrt override function below to answer.

Comment: @myname No problem. For future reference, this is a variation of Midpoint Circle Algorithm. I'd suggest you'd research on your own and learn more about it. :)